# sed RE error: repetition-operator operand invalid

Tags: macos, sed

When I try to run the following .sh code on my MacOS I get an error: "repetition-operator operand invalid"

Sounds like two repetition operators occur consecutively but I don't see that in regex. Maybe ".+?" is considered invalid syntax? Surprising

A code snippet:

```
export REGEX_DATETIME_DIFF="s/DATETIME_DIFF\((.+?),\s?(.+?),\s?(DAY|MINUTE|SECOND|HOUR|YEAR)\)/DATETIME_DIFF(\1, \2, '\3')/g"
export REGEX_SCHEMA='s/`physionet-data.(mimiciii_clinical|mimiciii_derived|mimiciii_notes).(.+?)`/\2/g'
export CONNSTR='-d mimic'

{ echo "${PSQL_PREAMBLE}; DROP TABLE IF EXISTS code_status; CREATE TABLE code_status AS "; cat code_status.sql; } | sed -E -e "${REGEX_DATETIME_DIFF}" | sed -E -e "${REGEX_SCHEMA}" | psql ${CONNSTR}`
```

Any clue?

Comment: `.+?` requires Perl-compatible regular expressions, but sed only supports basic and extended regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex `(.+?),` matches a shortest substring followed by a comma and
can be substituted with `([^,]+),`. It is same with `` (.+?)` ``.  Then would you modify the 1st two lines as:

```
export REGEX_DATETIME_DIFF="s/DATETIME_DIFF\(([^,]+),\s?([^,]+),\s?(DAY|MINUTE|SECOND|HOUR|YEAR)\)/DATETIME_DIFF(\1, \2, '\3')/g"
export REGEX_SCHEMA='s/`physionet-data.(mimiciii_clinical|mimiciii_derived|mimiciii_notes).([^`]+)`/\2/g'
```

Comment: this worked, thanks a million! sorry being a new contributor my feedback can't change the answer's grade :(

Comment: Yes, will do! Sorry, I was still typing another question as I got other error messages, which I think are related to sed still. They didn't appear in all tables, some seem to work fine so I think it depends on the column names...maybe? 

ERROR:  column "minute" does not exist
LINE 47: ...          DATETIME_DIFF(CHARTTIME, charttime_lag, MINUTE)/60
ERROR:  column "hour" does not exist
LINE 192:   , DATETIME_DIFF(endtime, starttime, HOUR) AS duration_hour...
sed: 1: "-e
": invalid command code -
ERROR:  relation "elixhauser_quan" does not exist
LINE 101: from  elixhauser_quan;

Comment: Thank you for the cooperation! As for the another problem, could you post it as a separate question? Then I will examine it later.

Answer (score 1):

@tshiono Sorry, will post the error messages I get as it is easier. This is just a snippet to give you intuition, there are others (esp. as minute hour are redundant columns)

many thanks for the help, much appreciated!

```
LINE 47: ...          DATETIME_DIFF(CHARTTIME, charttime_lag, MINUTE)/60
                                                                                                                                                ^
LINE 153: ...when DATETIME_DIFF(charttime, charttime_prev_row, HOUR) <= 2
                                                               ^
ERROR:  column "hour" does not exist
LINE 192:   , DATETIME_DIFF(endtime, starttime, HOUR) AS duration_hour...
                                                                                                                ^
LINE 189:   , DATETIME_DIFF(endtime, starttime, HOUR) AS duration_hour...
                                                ^
LINE 192:   , DATETIME_DIFF(endtime, starttime, HOUR) AS duration_hour...
                                                ^
sed: 1: "-e
": invalid command code -

ERROR:  relation "elixhauser_quan" does not exist
LINE 101: from  elixhauser_quan;
                ^
ERROR:  relation "ventilation_durations" does not exist
LINE 14: left join ventilation_durations vd
ERROR:  column "second" does not exist
LINE 49:   and DATETIME_DIFF(ce.charttime, ie.intime, SECOND) > 0
                                                      ^
ERROR:  relation "kdigo_creatinine" does not exist
LINE 27:   FROM kdigo_creatinine cr
                ^
ERROR:  relation "vitals_first_day" does not exist
LINE 51: left join vitals_first_day v
                   ^
```

Comment: Thank you for the update. But you are posting the question  in the `answer` pane. Please create a new thread of question with possibly a different title. Cheers.

Comment: I did: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65179324/re-sed-commande-error-column-xxx-does-not-exist?noredirect=1#comment115229991_65179324

Thanks again!

Comment: Hi, @tshiono, the above link is unavailable due to the question being raised is too detailed. Would you mind just replying to your thoughts on this question under this thread? Here is the code source https://github.com/MIT-LCP/mimic-code/blob/main/mimic-iii/concepts/postgres_make_concepts.sh. Thank you!

Comment: @LucileTer-Minassian Did you figure out this problem in the end? I meet the same issue and wonder if you can help. Thanks!

Comment: @ZhangYongheng thank you for the comment. I'd recommend to create your own thread of your specific problem with the minimal and reproduceable codes instead of referring other's question. Then you will have more opportunities to get the feedbacks.

Comment: Hi @tshiono, I did post the other thread on this question. However, the thread got closed due to "this question needs debugging details. It is not currently accepting answers"

Comment: @ZhangYongheng I'm afraid I cannot find your thread but you will need to edit your question to be
reopened and answered. There should be some reasons why your question has been closed.
You will need to understand and correct them.

Comment: @tshiono Hi, here is the new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69113864/run-sql-within-sh-file-under-the-search-path. Thanks!

Comment: @tshiono I suspect the error may relates to REGEX_DATETIME_DIFF. Thanks!

Comment: @tshiono https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69116392/regular-expression-in-postgresql-does-not-detect-the-quotes. This link addresses more on my thought in the last comment. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Installing the gnu version of sed fixed the problem for me, as I really need to use the (.*?) syntax

```
brew install gnu-sed
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/gnu-sed/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
```

Comment: This answer solves both the main question and the subsequent question OP asked