# Run .sql within .sh file under the search path

Tags: linux, postgresql, shell

Currently, the search path in `.sh` file is set as:

```sh
export PSQL_PREAMBLE='SET search_path TO public,mimiciii'
```

I am running:

```sh
{ echo "${PSQL_PREAMBLE}; DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ventilation_durations; CREATE TABLE ventilation_durations AS "; cat durations/ventilation_durations.sql; } | sed -r -e "${REGEX_DATETIME_DIFF}" | sed -r -e "${REGEX_SCHEMA}" | psql ${CONNSTR}
```

Question: After running the code above in the `.sh` file, it seems like the code I am running above did not catch the search path set in PSQL_PREAMBLE. It just does not catch the functions I created in the `mimiciii` schema

(The full script is here: https://github.com/MIT-LCP/mimic-code/blob/main/mimic-iii/concepts/postgres_make_concepts.sh)

Answer (score 2):

That should work just fine, but it seems unnecessarily complicated.

Just run

```sh
export PGOPTIONS=-csearch_path=public,mimiciii
```

at the beginning of your script, and `search_path` will automatically be set like that for all future `psql` invocations.

See the documentation of [`PGOPTIONS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html#id-1.7.3.21.3.4.11.1.1), the [`options`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNECT-OPTIONS) connection parameter and the [`-c` option of `postgres`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-postgres.html#APP-POSTGRES-OPTIONS).